How do I include a space in a bar chart to represent items with no information?
I have a database with the following structure. I know that there is one more factor in the “a” vector, which would be “C”, but there is no information. How do I make the C factor appear in a bar chart, with a count of 0. I can't include this space in the chart.
library(ggplot2)

a <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
b <- seq(1,5,1)

DF <- data.frame(a,b)

ggplot(data = DF,
       aes(x = a)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(aes(label=after_stat(count)),
            stat = "count")



Make sure to conver a to a factor that knows about C with something like DF$a <- factor(a, LETTERS[1:3]) and then add scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) to your plot
